# python tcp socket has delay on the first message on linux vps

Tags: python-3.x, linux, sockets, tcpserver, tcpsocket

Honestly, I am new in python tcp sockets and I wrote a simple code for the server side.
When I run the code locally, everything is fine and I receive the message from the local server immediately, but when I put the code on a vps (linux) and run the code with python3 test.py and send a message from client to the server, server receive the message from client and waits about 1 minute to send the message back to the client and after that everything is fine and the messages transfer between server and client without any delay. I tested other platforms such as nodejs, other vps and also setting ssl for the vps and using non-blocking mode and changed the recv() buffer size too but I faced the same thing.
I used telnet and a client with python and also faced the same issue.
I will be so thankful if you help me out with this.
Best regards

client (also telnet)

```
import socket

c = socket.socket()
c.connect(('my_ip',56112))
c.send(bytes("1",'utf-8'))
c.recv(1024).decode()
c.close()
```

server

```
import socket
s=socket.socket()
print("socket created!")
s.bind(('0.0.0.0',56112))
s.listen(3)
print("waiting for connections!")
while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        name = c.recv(1024).decode()
        print("connected with",addr,name)
        c.send(bytes("hi there",'utf-8'))
        c.close()
```

could you help me to solve this?

Comment: You should use a packet capture tool like Wireshark or tcpdump to see where the delay is happening -- on the sending side or the receiving side.

Comment: It is not clear from the question if the server sends the message immediately back or not, i.e. if the delay is in receiving the message or sending the message. You should be able to get this information from your code since the server is logging when it received a message.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich server gets the first message from client immediately but send back the message after 1 minute delay. after the delay, everything works well and there is no delay. this is the scenario of the vps side. on local everything works like a charm.

Comment: @AminHasanzadeh: *" but send back the message after 1 minute delay."* - do you mean that the server sends back the message after one minute delay or that it arrives at the client that late. Please check what your code is actually doing (add some debug messages) and please check at what happens on the wire (as suggested by Barmar).

Comment: @AminHasanzadeh - in case you're unfamiliar w/ tcpdump or don't know what names your network interfaces have:  `sudo tcpdump -i any port 56112` ...